# Defined variable gets back to undefined inside subscribe

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, subscribe

I'm a beginner so I think I might doing something wrong.
I try to code a CRUD that allows to add an image to a team when you create one.
I store the name of the file in the database and then I upload the image on the server back-end. A few days ago, everything was working perfectly but since yesterday, it won't upload the file. This is because the variable `this.currentFile`, which is defined on every change on the input, gets back to undefined after the data received from API was assigned to `this.team` (which is also undefined, whereas `data` is defined).

I found someone that said that `this` was undefined in `subscribe()` but mine is well defined.
I really don't know what's wrong, it's been hours I'm on this and I didn't find anything that could help, so any help would be greatly appreciated !

So here is the `submit()` method in `team-form.component.ts`

```
submit() {
    this.bindToModel();
    if(this.team.id == undefined) { //this.team and this.currentFile are well defined
      this.teamService.save(this.team).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.team = data; //this.team and this.currentFile get back to undefined at this point, even after data was assigned to this.team
          if(this.currentFile != undefined) {
            this.uploadService.upload(this.currentFile, this.team.id).subscribe({
              error: err => showError(this.toasterService, err.error.message),
              complete: () => {
                this.currentFile = null;
              }
            });
          }
        },
        error => showError(this.toasterService, error.message),
        () => { this.closeModalAndMessageSuccess()}
      );
    }else {
      this.teamService.update(this.team).subscribe({
        error: err => showError(this.toasterService, err.error.message),
        complete: () => this.closeModalAndMessageSuccess()
      })
    }
  }
```

Here is the `bindToModel()` method

```
bindToModel() {
    this.team.contestTypes = this.selectedContestTypes;
    this.selectedContestTypes = [];
    this.team.label = this.teamForm.get('label').value;
    if(this.currentFile != undefined) {
      this.team.logoPath = this.currentFile.name;
    } else {
      this.team.logoPath = null;
    }
  }
```

And the `selectFile(event)` method triggered when the user selects a file

```
selectFile(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
    }
  }
```

And the html of the input :

```
<div class="labelAndUpload">
    <label for="teamLogo"> Logo de l'équipe</label>
    <input type="file"
       id="teamLogo"
       (change)="selectFile($event)">  
</div>
```

EDIT :

So as @aditya_adi_98 suggested, I made a call to upload the file and save the team at the same time.
Now I think I have an issue with my back-end controller method syntax because I've got the following error :

```
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=---------------------------29202803211777703984242234963' not supported
```

Here is my new `submit()` method

```
  submit() {
    this.bindToModel();
    if(this.team.id == undefined) {
      var stringTeam = JSON.stringify(this.team);
      const frmData = new FormData();
      frmData.append("team", stringTeam);
      frmData.append("file", this.currentFile);

      this.teamService.save(frmData).subscribe({
        error: err => showError(this.toasterService, err.error.message),
        complete: () => this.closeModalAndMessageSuccess()
      });
    } else {
      this.teamService.update(this.team).subscribe({
        error: err => showError(this.toasterService, err.error.message),
        complete: () => this.closeModalAndMessageSuccess()
      })
    }
  }
```

Now the request

```
public save(formData: FormData) {
  return this.http.post<Team>(this.teamsUrl, formData);
}
```

And the back-end controller method (java). It's not modified yet to take in account the file I'm passing, but I just want the method to receive the request properly at the moment.

```
@PostMapping(path = TEAMS_URI, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<?> createTeam(@Valid @RequestParam("team") Team team, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws URISyntaxException {
        String message = bundle.getString(POST_TEAM);
        log.debug(message, team);
        Team teamSave = teamService.createTeam(team);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(teamSave, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Anyone who knows java here can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing two http calls where you can do this in one call..like send the file/image with `this.teamService.save(this.team)`

```
  const frmData = new FormData();      
  frmData.append("Upload", this.currentFile);
  frmData.append("team",this.team)
```

An Edit

you can also do this to watch your files getting uploaded, it is better to send a complete request and then wait for a response

```
this.http.post(BACKEND_URL+'/testfileupload', frmData,{responseType : 'text',reportProgress:true,observe :'events'})
    .subscribe(      
      (event: HttpEvent<any>)=>{
        switch(event.type){
          case HttpEventType.Sent:
            
            break;

          case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
            
            break;

          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
            this.showupload=true;
            this.changedetector.detectChanges()
            console.log(`uploaded ${this.progress}`);
            break;

          case HttpEventType.Response:
            this.showupload=false;
            this.doneupload=true;
            this.progress=0;
            this.currentFile=''
            this.changedetector.detectChanges(); 
            console.log("uploaded successfully")

            this.teamaddedsuccessful()
            setTimeout(()=>{
              this.doneupload=false;
              this.changedetector.detectChanges();
              this.modalService.dismissAll();
              this.toastr.success("File Uploaded Successful","Success")
              this.filetitle='';},3000)
        }
    
      },res=>{
        if(res.status == 404)
        {
          this.showupload=false;
          this.progress=0;
          this.changedetector.detectChanges(); 
          this.toastr.error("Error in File Upload","Error")
        }
      })
```

Comment: I thought it was a good practice to separate file manipulations from data operations

Comment: I can't add this.team to the formData : Argument of type 'Team' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'

Comment: 2 options 

(1) stringify team like : var stringteam = JSON.stringify(this.team) and then use frmData.append("team",stringteam)

OR

(2) pass team parameters separatly like :

frmData.append("team_id",this.team.id)
frmData.append("team_contestTypes",this.team.contestTypes)

Comment: contestTypes aren't strings, it's an array of ContestType. So I think the first option would be the best

Comment: Are you parsing the team [JSON.parse(team)] in Api to use it..??

Comment: I don't think so XD I'm going to do go check how to do that